# Maven-war-plugin doubles manifest.mf

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-war-plugin

I have a wab - web application bundle (osgi) and I need my custom manifest. In internet I found a solution - we create  src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and in pom:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>       
 <version>2.3</version><br>
 <configuration>
 <archive>
  <manifestFile>
   ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     
  </manifestFile>
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I use like this in final war I HAVE TWO MANIFEST.MF

1. /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2. /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Solution of this problem I found:

```
<packagingExcludes>/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/</packagingExcludes>
```

But I want to know the reason - why?. Is this a bug? O I don't understand something or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF comes from src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (copied by maven, like any other file placed in resources folder)

/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is created by maven-war-plugin

I believe you only need the second one.. so you should delete the manifest.mf in resources..

hope it helps!